# Update app on appstore with another Mac, without transferring identity possible?

Tags: app-store, certificate

I have a question about updating an app on appstore:

I have to update an app that was published by **another developer**. I have been given id/mdp to the developer portal, so I can download certificates and provisioning profile for distribution.

However, I know that to use these signing, I must use the identity used by the previous developer :

according to apple:

> **Transferring Your Identities**
>
> Once you have a healthy working code signing configuration set up it is recommended that you follow the steps in section Transfer Your Developer Profile to Another Computer of the Xcode 4 User Guide to create a backup of them. The backup can be used to restore your working code signing configuration from hardware failure, **or to enable code signing on additional Macs**, partitions, or OS X user accounts of your choice.

**I can't contact the previous developer...**

So here is my question :) If I generate new certificates, and publish the update:

- First, is it possible? ^^
- Second, if it is possible, will it appear like a normal update (a notification in the appstore update tab, and just a clic to update?) - *my fear is that it is impossible because of different signing and the user have to reinstall the app*

I really thank you if anyone have the answer.

Nice day,

Jer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are the administrator or the team leader of the same iOS Developer account under which the app was previously submitted, then you can revoke and re-generate all the certificates and provisioning profiles necessary to submit an update to that app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I do this, will it be transparent for the users that downloaded the app? Will they be able to update the app, even if it is different certificates? Thank you very much.